# "Cannot convert undefined or null to object" using polkadot.js with Acala network

Tags: acala

I'm using polkadot JS for Acala network and facing the issue below.
I cannot unstake or bridge token from Acala network to another one. The message that i got is as below. Could someone help me to resolve this issue?

Notes: I tried transfer some token INT from Interlay to Acala and that works normally
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Its a glitch with the metadata, i was getting the same error but tried again today and updated the metadata and its working now!

Comment: In order for this response to be useful to others, please provide the steps you took to update the metadata @Mark. 